# Go: edit in place of map values

Tags: dictionary, go

I wrote a [simple program](http://play.golang.org/p/ChmeymPRHG) using the Go Playground at golang.org.

The output is obviously:

```
second test
first test
```

Is there a way to edit the map value in place? I know I can't take the andress of `a.Things[key]`. So, is setting `a.Things[key] = firstTest` the only way to do it? Maybe with a function `ChangeThing(key string, value string)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do it by making the values of your map pointers to another struct.

http://play.golang.org/p/UouwDGuVpi

```
package main

import "fmt"

type A struct {
    Things map[string]*str
}

type str struct {
    s string
}

func (a A) ThingWithKey(key string) *str {
    return a.Things[key]
}

func main() {
    variable := A{}

    variable.Things = make(map[string]*str)
    variable.Things["first"] = &str{s:"first test"}

    firstTest := variable.ThingWithKey("first")
    firstTest.s = "second test"

    fmt.Println(firstTest.s)
    fmt.Println(variable.ThingWithKey("first").s)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't think about this. Your suggestion works great for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a pointer as the map value http://play.golang.org/p/BCsmhevGMX

Comment: I tried that actually, but the compiler wouldn't let me take an address of a string literal.  I see you got around that by assigning the string to a variable first and then taking the address of the variable.  I wonder why it is that I can take the address of a struct initialization but not of a string initialization.